# How to include recapcha in html from java servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, recaptcha

I want to include recapcha plugin in my web page from servlet. If i use  <%@ ..%> or  it won't include or show any recapcha.

Here is my **servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    final PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    String s="";

    String capchadisplay="<%@ ReCaptcha c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha(\"public-key" +
            "xxxxxxx \", \"private-key " +
            "\", false);\nout.print(c.createRecaptchaHtml(null, null));\n%>";

    String capchaimport="<%@ page language=\"java\" contentType=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"\n" +
            "pageEncoding=\"utf-8\" xmlns:jsp=\"http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page\"%>\n" +
            "\n<%@ page import=\"net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha\" %>\n" +
            "<%@ page import=\"net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory\" %>";

    String prefix="<!DOCTYPE html><html>\n<head>\n<title>Forms</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n";
    String subfix="</body>\n</html>\n";



    s=capchaimport.concat(prefix.concat(capchadisplay.concat(subfix)));

    out.write(s);

    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

Here is what  my **html page** should look like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
         pageEncoding="utf-8" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"%>

<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha" %>
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>
        Forms
      </title>
    </head>
    <body>   
      <% ReCaptcha c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha("pubic-key ", "private-key ", false);
         out.print(c.createRecaptchaHtml(null, null));%>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Instead of a recapcha widget i get the string inside the

Now i don't know if is the right way to display recapcah, but i am open to any suggestions, i just want to display it from my servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of researching and lots of headeaks i have manage to come up whit a right answer. I just use this code in my ***`capchadisplay`*** string:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   </script>
<noscript>
   <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=your_public_key"
     height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
   </textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
     value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reCAPTCHA Java Library provides a simple way to place a CAPTCHA on your Java-based website, helping you stop bots from abusing it. The library wraps the reCAPTCHA API.

Detailed step by step tutorial is provided [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java)

Comment: I've included those libs in my project, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Bro, it means you are definitely missing something... see it in detail and follow step by step.. As https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java is valid sources.. And developer.google is highly authentic guide...

Comment: the odd thing is if i start whit tomcat it works perfectly but in my jetty server doesn't work, i don't understand why. I've fallow every stem i even took the example from developer.google it doesn't display recapcha.

Comment: So issue is with you web server, if that is case please enable the debugging mode of server logs(use googling for help).. And find whats error on it either sever or client side.. You can also see the client side code errors on web browser debug console using F12